# How do I script mkfs asking "is entire device, not just one partition! Proceed anyway?"

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, bash

I'm trying to create a script that formats an Amazon EC2 EBS volume, so I can mount it.

From the command-line, it looks like this:

```
> mkfs -q -t ext4 /dev/sdf
/dev/sdf is entire device, not just one partition!
Proceed anyway? (y,n)
```

(The command is correct; no need to create a partition table for my purpose)

My problem: because this command is supposed to be run in an automated script, I can't have that question on the terminal; nobody will be answering and the script will hang. How do I avoid this?

I tried:

```
> echo y | mkfs -q -t ext4 /dev/sdf
```

but that doesn't do the trick. The -q option makes no difference either.

Comment: Perhaps you don't feel you need a partition table, but is there any reason why you *should not* have a partition table?

Comment: More things that can go wrong. Note my question is really a shell question, not a partition table question.

Comment: You're claim that "more things can go wrong" is completely baseless. It sounds like you're using your fear and misunderstanding to fuel your bad decisions.

Comment: Look, bahamat, I'm just talking about myself. I know that if I have to do two things instead of one, my likelihood of screwing up goes up. Maybe it's different for you, but none of this is the subject of this question at all anyway. #troll

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/mke2fs):

```
   -F     Force mke2fs to create a filesystem, even if the specified device is not a partition on a block special device, or  if  other
          parameters do not make sense.
```

So call `mkfs.ext4` directly instead of via `mkfs`, and add the `-F` parameter to ignore this warning.

Comment: Why wouldn't it make sense, according to the man page, to create a file system on the unpartitioned device?

Answer (score 3):

[`expect`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) is what you're looking for. Try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn mkfs -q -t ext4 /dev/sdf
expect "/dev/sdf is entire device, not just one partition!\nProceed anyway? (y,n)"
send -- "y\r"

expect eof
```

Comment: What does expect do differently than reading from stdin?

Comment: if there's another warning it won't send y